# Step Filter in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, filter

Greetings everyone!

In Step Filter, you can define the packages you wish to skip in Debug mode. One could notice, that it's a pain work to select *all* the packages you wish to skip if there is a small number of packages you really want to debug. My question is: is there any way to select packages you want to debug and that Eclipse simply steps over/ignores other packages?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest using breakpoints!

another great feature is "Run to Line" in the Editor or "Drop to Frame" in the Debug View. It doesn't make sense to debug a huge application from start to end.

Comment: Of course I use breakpoints. "Run to Line" is the thing I need. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Window > Preferences > Java > Debug > Step Filtering

You can choose step filter packages.